# Service Broker : Same Service in 'From' & 'To' clause in BEGIN DIALOG Statement

Tags: t-sql, service-broker

In my Service Broker design, I need to make an asynchronous calls and needed some work to get done in background (Inside SQL Server only, like updating tables).

There are certain points to be taken under consideration based on the requirement :

1. It's kind of one-way data push. Just place a message into the SB queue and forget. No acknowledgement required.
2. Only one database involved in the design. There is no need for multiple databases.
3. Message will be placed to the SB queue using a Stored Proc ( This SP will be called by an application).

By observing above points, it seems that requirement doesn't suits for creating 2 different SB services as only one service would suffice. I designed the scenario with having only one SB Service, and while creating a conversation dialog, I assigned same service name to the 'From' & 'To' clauses. Program pushes data to the SB queue and activator will activate associated Store Procedure.. It works just fine.

```
BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @RecordConversationHandle
FROM SERVICE **UpdateQueueStatus**
TO SERVICE '**UpdateQueueStatus**'
WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;
```

Please help me by any suggestion on the above proposed design.. ? Any suggestions/issues or anything which demands attention to improve the design for better performance & scalability would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Service broker is designed for dialogs, not monolog conversations. Don't design something new (There is tons of good reasons why they are always dialogs)

You can create sending service (Service1), witch is used for sending messages and receives "End Dialog" messages and ends dialog. The other (Service2) witch receives messages and does some processing with them + ends dialog when work is done.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason of two services in a dialog and dialog-oriented conversations is the ability to disable queue. The initiator's queue may be enabled while at the same time, for some purpose or reasons, the target's queue may be disabled. In this case, sedning messages runs without the "disabled queue" error and messages will wait in the transmition queue until the target queue become enabled again.

That is why a contract may contain just one message type, and a queue may be created without specifying any contract. It's the initiator's queue.

There is a caveat: [`BEGIN CONVERSATION TIMER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/begin-conversation-timer-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). It puts the standard message `https://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/DialogTimer` into a local queue the specified conversation dialog belongs to.

One use case when a dialog on the same service may be usefull, is a recovery process. However, in this case, there should be a specific message type received in a higher priority than ordinary messages. The activation procedure first receives a `recovery` message, tries to recover, rollback if unsuccessfull, then receives an ordinary messages and commits receiving messages of both the types or just rollback if unsuccessfull again.